# ISomeInterface referenceVariable = ClassThatImplementsIt

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently, I am learning ASP.NET MVC 5. I am stuck at one point in the book called Dependency injection. I will try my best to learn how to use it, but before I do that I would like you to help me. I started learning C# a few weeks ago and the one thing I haven't figured out yet is the interface. I know why and when to create it, but I don't really understand when it comes to making reference variables.

Let's say I have an interface called IValueCalculator. Then I have a class LINQValueCalculator which implements IValueCalculator. Now, here comes my misunderstanding.

```
LINQValueCalculator referenceVariable = new LINQValueCalculator();
```

This will create a new instance and will be bound to use with referenceVariable.
I can then use everything that interface told me to use and any added stuff to the class.

But, what if I do this...

```
IValueCalculator referenceVariable = new LINQValueCalculator();
```

What is the difference? Can I still do the same thing as before or has something changed?

What if I had something like this

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    private IValueCalculator calc;

    public ShoppingCart(IValueCalculator calcParam)
    {
        calc = calcParam;
    }
```

This means I can put only those object's references which implement that interface right? Or am I wrong?

When I truly understand the point under all this, I will then continue learning Ninject (DI).

Answer (score 1):

The underlying object is still a `LINQValueCalculator` but you can only refer to the `IValueCalculator` methods and properties while using `referenceVariable` because that variable is just the interface.

To make use of any of the properties of `LINQValueCalculator` you'll have to cast the variable. You can do this each time you need to use it:

```
((LINQValueCalculator)referenceVariable).SomeMethod();
```

or just the once:

```
var anotherReference = (LINQValueCalculator)referenceVariable;
```

Here, `anotherReference` and `referenceVariable` are references to the same object so changes to one will be reflected in the other.

Using the interface means that you can pass the object to other code that doesn't know (or need to know) about `LINQValueCalculator`, but acts on the properties and methods of `IValueCalculator`.

Comment: Before going deeper, why do people use referenceVars only for interface properties and methods? Everytime I look at my book, that's always the case. Is it because people really want only to access the interface stuff, rather than those who implement it? What about child and parent, does the same apply too?

Comment: @xForcer Correct. We use interfaces because we don't care about how it's implemented, we just care that it does implement that interface. This allows our code to not be too tightly coupled, making it more testable and easier to swap things out without breaking other things. I suggest [this excellent video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412).

Comment: Thank you @mason for strengthening my knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference? Can I still do the same thing as before or has something changed?

You can do the same things :-) 
Unless if the concrete type offer more method than the interface !

> This means I can put only those object's references which implement that interface right? Or am I wrong?

And you're right !

The benefits of using interface in the last case is that you can receive an object that implements `IValueCalculator` but you (really) don't care about the concrete type.

If you decide to create a second concrete type that implements the `IValueCalculator` (more performant maybe ?), you can do it and inject it into `ShoppingCart` constructor without change the `ShoppingCart` code !